# ImageField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I am attempting to build a basic database of song information, regarding artists, songs and albums. On my page for any given album I am attempting to display the album art for a given album. I am using the built-in image upload feature within Django Admin to upload the images. The images urls are being saved correctly within mysql (I checked), but the images are not being displayed on the site. From what I have read online the possible problematic areas are either in the URLs file(which I have not modified to accommodate media) or in my MEDIA_URL, but I have followed instructions as Django has outlined. Below I am linking the code I think is relevant. Thank you in advance for the help!

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from Radio.models import Song, Artist, Album

def SongsAll(request):
    songs = Song.objects.all().order_by('songName')
    context = {'songs' : songs}
    return render_to_response('songsall.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def SpecificSong(request, songname):
    song = Song.objects.get(songName = songname)
    context = {'song':song}
    return render_to_response('specificsong.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def SpecificArtist(request, artistname):
    singer = Artist.objects.get(artistName = artistname)
    songs = Song.objects.filter(artist = singer)
    context = {'songs':songs}
    return render_to_response('specificartist.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def SpecificAlbum(request, albumname):
    album = Album.objects.get(albumName = albumname)
    songs = Song.objects.filter(album = album)
    context = {'songs':songs}
    return render_to_response('specificalbum.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### settings.py (only the relevant parts)

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/kyle/Downloads/Django-1.5.1/radioSite/media/'

MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
```

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Artist(models.Model):
    artistName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    artistInfo = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.artistName

class Album(models.Model):
    albumName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Release Date')
    albumInfo = models.TextField()
    albumArt = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/albumart/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.albumName

class Song(models.Model):
    songName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.songName
```

### base.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/Radio.css"/>
     {% block extended %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<div id="pageContainer">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### specificalbum.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
   <div id="singlealbum">
       <p><img src="{{ songs.0.album.albumart.url }}"/>Name: {{ songs.0.album }}</p>
       <p>Artist:{{ songs.0.artist }}</a></p>
       <p>Song list:</p>
            {% for song in songs %}
               <p><a href="/songs/{{ song }}/">{{ song }}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your images actually getting uploaded somewhere where a web server is expecting to serve them?

From your `MEDIA_URL` setting I'm guessing that you're trying to get the Django server to serve the images.  You can check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user) for how to do this during development, or if you're just learning Django, but please don't try to do this for anything at all serious - you'll be much better served by using a dedicated web server like Apache or the like.

Comment: The images are getting uploaded within ../media/images/albumart
I read over the documentation and updated my urls.py to reflect what they recommend, but I am still having the same problem. I dont know if this is worth noting but when I view the html of the webpage loaded the img src is an empty string.

Comment: Right, but is there anything running that will provide the images back to the user's browser?  If you're just using the Django development server, you can follow the documentation I linked to make it start doing so - with all the associated warnings about how you should not do this in a final deployment.  More usually, you'd have a web server handling that kind of content, independent of your Django app.

Comment: I do not, would you recommend switching now to have my web server be Apache or is it OK to learn using the Django web server?

Comment: If you're just doing a project to learn how Django works, it's OK to use the Django web server.  If you expect to ever actually leave it running full time or expose it to real use, at some point you'll need to set up a dedicated server - Apache is one common option, but not the only one.  lighttpd shows up in many recommendations as well, just for instance.